# Instabot, ERROR - Request returns 400 error! Python

Tags: python-3.x, instagram

he intentado usar este código, pero me genera error, he revisado mi usuario y clave, he cerrado sesión y vuelto a iniciar para probar la clave y la he cambiado, aun me sigue generando el mismo error, si alguien sabe la razón, agradezco su ayuda.

```
# importar la clase a utilizar
from instabot import Bot 
# crear el nuevo objeto
bot = Bot()
bot.login(ask_for_code=True) 
bot.login(username="xxxxxxxxxxx", password="xxxxxxxx*+")
bot.follow_followers("xxxxx01")
```

Este es el error

```
C:\Programas_Python>bot_instagram.py
2021-07-23 09:40:13,302 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2021-07-23 09:40:13,307 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2021-07-23 09:40:19,607 - ERROR - Request returns 400 error!
2021-07-23 09:40:19,607 - INFO - Instagram's error message: The password you entered is 
incorrect. Please try again.
2021-07-23 09:40:19,611 - INFO - Error type: bad_password
2021-07-23 09:40:19,617 - ERROR - Failed to login go to instagram and change your password
2021-07-23 09:40:19,617 - INFO - Username or password is incorrect.
```

Esta es mi versión de Python

```
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on 
    win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tiene pinta que ese primer bot.login en el que no usas las credenciales sino que pones un parámetro `ask_for_code` que no se sabe para qué es, es el que está fallando y ya lo demás no importa. La [documentación oficial](https://instagrambot.github.io/docs/en/For_developers.html#Methods) no lo menciona por ninguna parte, ¿qué intentas ahí?

Prueba sin esa línea

```
# importar la clase a utilizar
from instabot import Bot 
# crear el nuevo objeto
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="xxxxxxxxxxx", password="xxxxxxxx*+")
bot.follow_followers("xxxxx01")
```

También he podido [ver](https://github.com/ohld/igbot/issues/1293) que puedes usar el `ask_for_code` en los parámetros, pero:

```
from instabot import Bot  # noqa: E402

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=True)
parser.add_argument("-u", type=str, help="username")
parser.add_argument("-p", type=str, help="password")
parser.add_argument("-proxy", type=str, help="proxy")
parser.add_argument("users", type=str, nargs="+", help="users")
args = parser.parse_args()

bot = Bot()
bot.login(username=args.u, password=args.p, proxy=args.proxy, ask_for_code=True)
```

Pero debes crear el archivo cookie.json y guardar la cookie para que el inicio de sesión pueda guardar el resultado de autenticarse. Siguiendo [este comentario](https://github.com/ohld/igbot/issues/1293#issuecomment-610935629), debes:

- Iniciar sesión en instagram en un navegador normal, y ver en herramientas de dev las cookies creadas
- Crear un archivo en el subdirectorio config llamado `{username}_uuid_and_cookie.json` con el contenido que indican en el comentario

```
{
  "uuids": {
    "phone_id": "5c7ee0b6-d420-4c83-b252-01503e701340",
    "uuid": "4e3eb35e-aa39-39d1-b16d-204a45e4aa73",
    "client_session_id": "6abc534e-0213-5e3c-2159-64eef3dd42e7",
    "advertising_id": "3f0397c6-5505-1123-ba15-5dd3a8acce06",
    "device_id": "android-3f8a1301e66b623e"},
    "cookie": {
      "csrftoken": "xxx",
      "ds_user": "xxx (your username)",
      "ds_user_id": "xxx",
      "ig_direct_region_hint": "FRC",
      "ig_did": "xxx",
      "igfl": "xxx (your username)",
      "is_starred_enabled": "yes",
      "mid": "xxx",
      "rur": "xxx",
      "sessionid": "xxx",
      "shbid": "xxx",
      "shbts": "xxx",
      "urlgen": "xxx"
    },
    "timing_value": {
      "last_login": 1584284362.348525,
      "last_experiments": 1584284361.195544
    },
    "device_settings": {
      "app_version": "117.0.0.28.123",
      "android_version": "28",
      "android_release": "9.0",
      "dpi": "420dpi",
      "resolution": "1080x1920",
      "manufacturer": "Huawei",
      "device": "Mate 10 Pro",
      "model": "Mate 10 Pro",
      "cpu": "qcom",
      "version_code": "180322800"
    },
    "user_agent": "Instagram 117.0.0.28.123 Android (28/9.0; 420dpi; 1080x1920; Huawei; HUAWEI MATE 10 PRO; Mate10Pro; qcom; de_DE; 180322800)"
}
```

Reemplaza los `xxx` con los valores en la cookie.

- Al correr tu py, va a actualizar esto al iniciar sesión de nuevo.

Comment: Hola, Gracias ´por responder, probé el código sin esta bot.login(ask_for_code=True)  línea  y me sigue generando el error, el mismo error que he publicado, ahora mismo cree una cuenta nueva en instagram y probé el código y me genera el mismo error, no entiendo he leído que a muchos les ha funcionado

Comment: Cuando pones `password="xxxxxxxx*+"`, estás manipulando la contraseña de alguna forma? Tienes 2FA habilitado para esa cuenta? El error está en tus credenciales o en el entorno, no hay muchas opciones

Comment: No, simplemente coloco la clave que uso para ingresar y me funciona tanto en el teléfono como en la aplicación desktop, No tengo habilitado el 2FA, además, he intentado con una cuenta nueva y el código me genera el  mismo ERROR, es lo que me parece extraño.

Comment: @JuancarlosPantoja te recomiendo revisar la versión que estás usando de la librería, porque el mensaje de error que recibes no es el mismo que se ve en [el código](https://github.com/instagrambot/api/blob/master/api.py)

Comment: @JuancarlosPantoja actualicé la respuesta con algo que puede servirte.

Comment: ok Muchas gracias  @Alfabravo, voy a probra el código